# Capturing logs when data is copied between two blob storages in different Azure accounts

Tags: azure

I am trying to build up a small automation to detect cases when a file on Azure blob storage is copied to another blob in a different Azure account, or different Azure subscription. Which log sources should I be looking at? I tried setting up the Diagnostic setting for the blob but not sure how if that is the write approach.

I looked at Azcopy and based on Microsoft's definition, it seems like the results of Azcopy will only be written locally on the system. I am not sure how true my assumption is.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried setting up the Diagnostic setting for the blob but not sure how if that is the write approach.
```

- Setting up diagnostic settings for Azure Blob Storage is the right approach to monitor changes in the storage.
- . To enable Azure Storage diagnostics, log in to the Azure portal, access your storage account, and click on Diagnostic settings (classic) given under Monitoring (classic) settings and choose required blob properties and logging like Read, Write, Delete based on your requirement as shown in below image.

[image]

- Then to collect resource logs, choose Diagnostic settings under monitoring and choose your blob storage account create a diagnostic setting as the type of storage that you want to monitor.
  [image]
- Then select Metrics and select destination storage account details as mentioned below.
  [image]
- Once the diagnostic settings are enabled, the Storage Analytics logs will start streaming to the destination you specified. You can then use tools like Azure Monitor, Log Analytics to analyze and visualize the logs.

  Reference [document](https://help.sumologic.com/docs/send-data/collect-from-other-data-sources/azure-blob-storage/collect-logs-azure-blob-storage/) for more information.

  ```
   I looked at Azcopy and based on Microsoft's definition, it seems like the results of Azcopy will only be written locally on the system. I am not sure how true my assumption is.
  ```
- AzCopy is a command-line tool that is used to upload and download blobs/files from or to the Azure Blob Storage. The logs generated by AzCopy are stored locally on the system
  . It is possible to specify storage class with azcopy using the command line tool that moves data into and out of Azure Storage

  For reference .[log analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-overview) MS document
  .